# How to provide routes with guards for unit testing Angular 6 Component?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, angular6, angular-router-guards

I have an **Angular 6** component that has input fields.  If any of the input fields fail validation if the user tries to navigate away, a guard will trigger on the `canDeactivate` function.  The guard is generic because this logic needs to happen on more than one component in the app.  It works beautifully running it, but when I attempt to unit test this behavior, the `canDeactivate` function in the guard is never reached.  The guard itself is reached, but never the function.  Am I providing the guard in an incorrect way?

**Guard Component Interface**

```
export interface GuardComponent {
    canDeactivate: () => Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean;
}
```

**CanDeactivateGuard**

```
export class CanDeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate<GuardComponent> {
    constructor() { }

    canDeactivate(component: GuardComponent): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
        return component.canDeactivate();
    }
}
```

**Component**

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, GuardComponent {

...

    canDeactivate() {
        if (!this.form.invalid) {
            return true;
        }
        this.isError = true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

**spec**

```
const routes = [
    {
        path: 'my-component',
        component: MyComponent,
        canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard],
    },
    {
        path: 'my-component-2',
        component: MyComponent2
    }
];

beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [ RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(routes) ],
        declarations: [ MyComponent, MyComponent2 ],
        providers: [ CanDeactivateGuard ],
    }).compileComponents();
}));

beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixutre.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
});    

it('should restrict route change if validation fails', fakeAsync(inject([Router, Location, CanDeactivateGuard], (router: Router, location: Location, guard: CanDeactivateGuard) => {
    const textbox = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#inputField')).nativeElement;
    const canDeactivateSpy = spyOn(guard, 'canDeactivate');
    const componentDeactivateSpy = spyOn(component, 'canDeactivate');

    // anything lower than 0 will fail the form
    textbox.value = '-10';
    fixture.detectChanges();

    router.navigate(['/my-page-2']).then(() => {
        expect(location.path()).toBe('/my-component');  // path doesn't change because guard blocks it due to form being invalid
        expect(canDeactivateSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(componentDeactivateSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
})));
```

The test fails because the `canDeactivate` functions are never reached.